# how can i unblock an ip address on my machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, windows-8, windows-firewall

I installed some app that hacked my computer and I cleared this app but this app block google ip on my windows firewall but I cannot find the rule that blocked google on my machine I don't want to do a format I just want to find where is the ip is blocked or even allow the ip again

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

I notice that the virus requests netsh.exe while executed

That's not duplicated question I have no virus issue now , there is only a certain ip cannot be unblocked unless I do a format that's emans my firewall block it some where

Comment: @DavidPostill I removed the virus I want only to ublock the blocked ip

Comment: @DavidPostill also this is not duplicated question the question you refer is different by a mile

Comment: Properly removing the infection would have unblocked the up address

Comment: @Ramhound I have mention that the exe virus when it requested it called `netsh` at its start up that's means its applied some rules removing the infection will not remove fire wall Rules ...

Comment: "netsh advfirewall reset" does remove the rules or you can manually remove the exception yourself

Comment: I did that still the ip is block

Comment: @Raelpaul that means your still infected with malware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long analysis Problem is located The Bad file is applying netsh rules with special policy using `netsh advfirewall reset` will not help it will leave the policy as it is with the same values filters so by deleting the policy issue solved , the other answer is considered as wrong answer that's why I posted my correct answer to help others , its not malware nor spyware or any thing else ..

simply I opened CMD as administrator and delete netsh rules 
eg.

```
netsh ipsec static delete rule ...
```

Comment: You should edit your answer and provide specifics on what exactly fixes your problem

Comment: @Ramhound edited

Answer (score 0):

No method of removing any virus is ever 100% guaranteed.
You computer can not be trusted anymore, unless you do a full format and re-install from scratch.

Having said that, try these steps:

1. Disable the Windows firewall. If it is still blocked it isn't caused by the firewall.
2. Remove the file called "hosts" in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
3. If that also doesn't bring a solution there is still malware left on your computer. Go back to my initial statement at the top.

Comment: 2.... or check it contains only default data &/or data entered by yourself manually.

Comment: @Tetsujin The default data is actually nothing (the localhost entry isn't actually used by Windows but handled in the internal name-resolver). If the poster is savvy enough to have hand-editted the hosts file I presume he can also tell the difference between his own edits and any extras that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry, I'm used to Mac, which has some basic defaults.

Comment: I used process hacker to identify if there is  remote control on my pc and seems my pc is pretty clean , I did place that virus on other pc for test and its doing the same thing when it runs it called `netsh` and the ip that I am trying to unblock get blocked immediately.. it isn't malware  or kinda infection there must be something deeper with the firewall

Comment: @Raelpaul "I did place that virus on other pc for test" now you have two broken machines ...

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah this is only for analysis purpose I just want to track down the block method  :)

Comment: @Realpaul host-file, Windows firewall, additional extra firewall installed by virus, name-resolver hijack by virus, traffic interceptor in tcp/ip stack or in the NDIS layer installed by the virus.... There are probably a dozen more methods I can't immediately remember. Most viri usually use multiple methods, with various levels of difficulty to detect and even more difficult to remove.

Comment: @Tonny Your answer is totally wrong nothing should be done with hosts files I have found the real firewall rules and posted correct answer for certain issue